# Why is the format string for int %d in C?

Tags: c

Why did the creators of C choose `%d` as the format specifier and not say `%i`? In other words, how is `d` related to an integer?

Comment: x - hex. o - octal. ? - decimal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%d` stands for *decimal*, while `%i` stands for *integer*. Both are valid format specifiers.

The difference is that, for `scanf` and friends, `%i` will match numbers with different bases (as if you pass `strtol` a `0` base), but `%d` only with base 10. For `printf` it is the same.

Answer (score 2):

`%d` is meant of integer decimal literals only. While
`%i` Can be used with any of the integer literals in any form, like Octal form, hexadecimal form and decimal form(obviously).
For the sake of simplicity I am adding this example

```
#include <stdio.h> 
  
int main() 
{ 
    int a;
    scanf("%d", a);
    scanf("%i", a) ;
  
    return 0; 
}
```

Now, try to run this program in your IDE and provide an input which is in hexadecimal form for the first scanf() statement, this will immediately stop the program. While, if we use %i in space of "%d" we are allowed to input hexadecimal values and octal value too.

Answer (score 1):

It means "decimal integer"